# How to run Flask app using gunicorn?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

The question can be devided on two separate parts.

1. I have the following project stucture

   ```
   |- project
   |   |-- app/ - directory with actual project code
   |   |-- app.py - imports something from app/ and call create_app
   ```

   When I run `gunicorn` I should point him to `app` object which is actually created in `app.py`. So I get an error because gunicorn treats `app:app` as a package. The only way is to rename something?
2. I use factory method to create app. So I import `create_app` fuction in app.py and pass it to `Manager` from `flask.ext.script`. I pass manager object to gunicorn. In this case gunicorn runs correctly but once the first request comes I get the following error:

   ```
   [2015-03-25 15:38:11 +0000] [14395] [ERROR] Error handling request
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/opt/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 52, in handle
   self.handle_request(listener_name, req, client, addr)
     File "/opt/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 159, in handle_request
   super(GeventWorker, self).handle_request(*args)
     File "/opt/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line 105, in handle_request
       respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
   TypeError: __call__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
   ```

   Perhaps I could create some file `wsgi.py` and provide current app for gunicorn ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have issues if two things named "app" are in the same directory in Python's path.

You need to pass a Flask app instance directly to gunicorn.  The command line manager is not a WSGI app, which is why you get that error.

You can simply point gunicorn directly at a call to your app factory, there is no need for any intermediate code.

```
gunicorn app:create_app()
```